# What should I do that GWT use <th> instead of <td>?

Tags: gwt

To build a HTML table I use direct DOM instead of a predefined Widget to set thead and tbody. But when I insert a cell with the insertCell() method GWT inserts an td element but should insert an th element.

So

```
TableElement table = Document.get().createTableElement();
TableSectionElement thead = table.createTHead();
TableRowElement headRow = thead.insertRow(-1);
headRow.insertCell(-1).setInnerText( "header1" );
```

gives

```
table/thead/tr/td
```

but should give

```
table/thead/tr/th
```

Any idea how to solve this problem? Use the "old-school" DOM.createXXX()-Methods?

Answer (score 5):

you may create and add  manually:

```
final TableCellElement th = Document.get().createTHElement();
th.setInnerText("i'm th!");
headRow.appendChild(th);
```

and you get:

```
<table><thead><tr><td>header1</td><th>i'm th!</th></tr></thead></table>
```